# Excel VBA missing the element 'Date'

Tags: excel, vba, datetime, libraries

I used 'MS Office Home Use 2010' until December 2022 and also programmed VBA. After replacing the motherboard and reactivating Windows 10, MS Office could no longer be activated. I bought 'MS Office Home & Student 2021', which could be activated, but does not find a suitable library in my VBA macros for the data type 'Date'. So far I could not find out which library I need and how to include it. When I display all libraries with F2, I see 'DataTime' and as an element of it also 'Date'. What can I do to activate the needed libraries ?

I have activated various libraries, but without success and I need the names of the missing libraries.

Comment: `VBA.DateTime.Date` is part of the standard libray. You may need a clean install of Office.

Comment: If you look in Tools > References, check whether any references are marked as "MISSING:" and uncheck them. Missing references sometimes cause very odd errors which have nothing to do with the reference itself